# Spinning up the Moon: does it survive the event?

Tags: hard-science, moons, astrophysics

The year is 2xxx. A large asteroid is spotted on a collision course with Earth. The more time it passes, the more it is clear that the impact cannot be avoided. But when most of humanity is starting to panic, detailed calculations show that the asteroid will strike the Moon with a very tangential angle, somewhere between 5 and 10 degrees above the horizon.

Is it possible for such an impact to spin up the Moon rotation, removing the tidal locking with Earth while not obliterating our satellite?

About the expected rotation rate of the Moon after the impact, I was thinking of having it such that a stationary Earth observer would see the same view of the Moon surface after 280 days (assuming the post-impact Moon is still there).

Comment: Should we assume an impact that wouldn't take a chunk out of the moon? And should we assume an impact that isn't hard enough to substantially push the moon away from or closer to the Earth? Even a tangential impact has this possibility, if I remember my astronomy. Some of the force always translates to the polar vector from the planet unless the impact is dead-center of a homogeneous solid tangential to the orbit.

Comment: @JBH, if you have the math to show that, it count as an answer for me

Comment: OK, let me see if I can dig it up. It was a pool ball experiment... that was 30+ years ago... What about the two limitation questions?

Comment: @JBH, I think some chunks will be ejected away (that might be a follow up question) unless the asteroid is a blob of jello. The second one I think it belongs to an answer.

Comment: The main problem with such an impact is, that we would have known the "asteroid" in question like since the 19th century. The impact would have to be gigantonormous, and the corresponding impactor would be rather hard to miss with our current technology.

Comment: You can quickly Google how much energy it would take to end the tidal locking. I think that this sort of research would benefit the question. Get an idea of the dimensions first.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica, the introduction to the question can be skipped. The outcome of the impact is not affect by us knowing about the impactor or not

Comment: Well, my point is that your story would be obviously inconsistent with our history. We know all sufficiently large bodies in the inner solar system by now. So, you would need to postulate at least that the "asteroid" is comming from interstellar space. This, of course, would allow for a rather minimal warning time, and a very high impact speed of roughly $17\frac{km}{s}$ to $77\frac{km}{s}$, depending on whether the impactor approaches earth prograde or retrograde on its way around the sun. This would also mean that there won't be any time to do anything about it once the impactor is spotted.

Comment: Maybe this or it's references helps: https://impact.ese.ic.ac.uk/ImpactEarth/ImpactEffects/effects.pdf. They say they didn't do the math for changes in orbital parameters or axis tilt because if the impactor is big enough for earth for such changes to be noticable there will be nobody there to notice them anyway. Or so :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer. As it was pointed out in the Comments under here, the value I got for the Energy is most likely not right. The Error appears to come from a false conversation from Joule to N. This resulted in the Impactor being bigger than it needs to be.
The Simulations I ran are also basic in the sense that they use 10000 Particels for the Moon and 5000 for the Impactor. Thus some detail is missing. Not to mention Computing Errors and such.
This means, while the Impactor I got out in the end would still work, the actual Impactor would be smaller.

**Round 2 but with Math**

So first a heads up, since some people had problems with my comment, here is the full thing with all the Math, some Simulations and a few Estimations. Its time to open Clion, get those Floating Point Int´s out and do some big boy Math !

**First things first**

The Moon is locked to the Earth, which, as you probably know, means that the Moon rotates 360 degrees around itself for a full Rotation around the Earth. So in a sense, it doesn't rotate at all from over POV. Which is why I will say that the Moon has 0* of Rotation before the Impact.

**The New Rotation**

You said that an Observer from Earth should see the same side of the Moon after 280 Days. Which means the Moon now Rotates 360* in 280 Days. Or 9/7* for each day. Around 1,28* / day. Or, as we are good and use SI Base Unites, 1,28* each 86400 Seconds. Which is equal to 1/67200* / second.

This Value, 1/67200*/s, is or Target Rotation, or Angular Momentum or Whatever. Its the spin we need to SOMEHOW, get into the Moon.

**A basic Estimation**

Of course, this Value means nothing to us. "Oh Great, only 1/67200* / s, that's not to bad". Yeah nobody knows what that is in Terms of Energy. Luckily for us, someone thought the same and create a Formula which tells us how much or Value is worth in terms of E_Kin. Or Kinetic Energy.

K = 1/2 * i * w² => Kinetic Energy = 1/2 Moment of Inertia * (Angular Speed)².

So lets break this down first.

The Moment of Inertia is defined as I = L / w. You will notice that we have "w" twice. Thus the next step is to figure out w.

For w, we only need the rate of Change and the Radius. The Rate of Change is basically the Velocity of the Rotation. To figure that out, we can take the circumference of the Moon of 10.921 km and Multiply it by or 1/67200*/s. Why can we do this ? Because the 10,921km are basically 360* and so by Multiplying it with or Value, we see how many km are Traveled in that time. Which turns out to be: 0.1625km. Or 162,5 Meters / s.

Thus, the Angular Velocity of the Moon is: w = v x r / |r|² -> 0.00001488 radians /s. Nice.

With w out of the way, we only need L to solve the Equation. We use L = Mass*Velocity*Radius. So or L = MassMoon * 162,5m/s * 10921km => L = 1,31*10^28T

Now we can finally solve for or Kinetic Energy. Which turns out to be 1,06*10^30N.

**The Numbers, what do they mean ?**

This 1,06*10^30N is more or less the force needed to induce this the Target Rotation into the Moon.

**Mass vs Velocity of the Impactor**

So, we got a Number with "N" as its unit. That is pretty cool since we can now use E_Kin = 1/2m*v². Which is an Equation that gives us the Kinetic Energy for any Given Object with any given Mass at any given Velocity as long as non of these Numbers are: [image]

Since we are lucky today, we can make a good guess to the Velocity of the Impactor. According to the Wiki, the avg. Velocity for an Asteroid hitting earth is 17km/s. Which odd to be the fly by Velocity too.

With that Number, we can now solve E = 1/2 m * v² for m.

m = E / (1/2*v²) or 2E/v² if you like. Same same.

So: m = 1,06*10^30N / 0,5*(17000m/s)² => 7,335*10^21kg

That's a lot. Sill less than the Earth though. But to put it into context, Ceres has a mass of 0.0128 Moons. Or Impactor is around 8 Times more Massive. So the Impactor alone is around 0.1 Moon Masses.

Again, the Impactor is a Minor Planet at this point. Sure if it was faster, it would be less massive, but we want realistic numbers.

**How would that actually look ?**

So, the Impactor is 0.1 Moon Masses. How big is it ? That depends on the Density. It is likely that such an Impactor would be either a Moon or a Proto Planet from the Asteroid belt. Like Ceres. So I'll take the Density of Ceres of 2,162g/cm³.

Now we can get a feeling for how big the Impactor is. The Equation is simply Volume = mass / Density.

Meaning for or Impactor we take: Volume = (7,335*10^21kg * 1000) / 2,162g/cm³ to get a total Volume of 3,39*10^24 cm³. Which is 3390000000 km³. Now we can use the Formula for the Volume of a Sphere, V = 4/3 Pi*r³ to get the Radius. Which is:

r = 3root(3*V / 4*Pi). Which turns out to be 931km for the Radius. So needless to say, it is pretty big. And it is not even that much smaller than the Moon. Like Jesus...

Now the Funny part, visuals :D

Btw, you can be happy I work in the VFX Industry, otherwise you would have needed to look at boring 2D Graphics D:

[image]

This Render shows you how such a big Impactor would look like for Earth.

[image]

This one shows the Relative size of the Impactor compared to the Moon and Earth.

[image]

And this is just cool. The Impactor compared to North America.

**The Problem with all of this**

So what I essentially did was calculate how big an Impactor would have to be in order to induce the needed amount of Energy into the Moon. But it doesn't work like this.

In the real world, large bodies such as the Moon behave like Fluids. So the Collision would "melt" into itself. Overall, what effect that will have is hard to tell. It might be that all the forces cancel out and we get the amount of Rotation we want. Or not. It is impossible to say without running actual Simulations. Which did on a VERY small scale. The long and short of it is that OVERALL, the rotation gained is about right. But it just heavily depends on the Starting Conditions.

Meaning, the Impactor i showed can do what you want, if the conditions are right. Right means a very Horizontal Impact angle, around the 1-5 degrees you mentioned, a relatively low Impact Velocity and the Earth should be as far away as she can get. Otherwise too much debris doesn't go into Orbit around the Moon but instead crash on Earth.

**Does the Moon come out on top ?**

In every simulation I did except the Meme ones, it did. As long as you don't shoot the Impactor at Railgun Velocities at the Moon, it is just not enough force to destroy it.

In every case, the Moon pretty much turned into a Fluid and stabilized after a few Million years. The Amount of Debris is a problem though, since in every case continent sized Rocks fell on Earth. So you know, Mass extinction and stuff.

Comment: "So the Moon has a Radius of like 1700km or so. Meaning or Impactor would sort of have to have a Radius of 850km in induce the same sort of Spin we saw in the Earth Theia example."... is this what "Hard Science" looks like? no wonder I got it wrong with my approach. Thank you, this is very instructional.

Comment: I remeber your comment :D It was pretty good although you didnt accout fro the Fluid Dynamics of such an Impact. 
The first version of my comment refered to yours but oh well, your comment is gone. 

So, the way i see it, there is no Hard Science answer here. We dont know the sizes, mass, velocity, angle, density and so on of the Impactor. So all we can do is use Theia as an example and assume how it would work. I mean, you giant Joule number had no weight to it. No relation with reality what so ever as you i belive admited

Comment: The weakness of the comparison with the Theia collision is, that that collision produced an earth that was spinning much faster than it does today. The excess speed has since been used to lift the moon up to its current orbit, and earth's rotation is still lifting the moon some centimeters every year, further slowing the rotation. The rotation that the OP wants to achieve is much lower, so a much smaller impactor is needed. Nevertheless, it would still probably turn the entire moon into a glowing ball of lava and bombard the earth with quite a bit of debris.

Comment: But thats the thing isnt it ? We cant really say anything with certainty. The effect of the Impactor is determend by 2 major factors. The Velocity and Mass. The 2 smaller factors are Density and the Impact angle. 
So in a sense, we have 4 Variables. Anything can happen. If op said "The Impactor is this big", it would have been easier to say. But without that Information, the Theia impact appeared to me to be the best comparision. But is flawed of course. 

I would still think though that the Impactor would be around the sizes of Ceres...

Comment: Well, the speed has a lower bound in the moon's system escape velocity (escape from moon prograde to also escape earth's gravity), which is $2.42\frac{km}{s}$. And that gives an upper bound to the necessary mass. Sorry, I don't have the ability to actually do these calculations right now. The further away the impactor starts  from earth, the higher the impact speed, until it reaches some tens of kilometers per second coming from interstellar space. Unfortunately, the faster the impact, and thus the lighter the impactor, the more energy is released, heating the moon and creating debris.

Comment: Updated my Comment with some high level stuff. 

In my new Comment, i assumed an Impact velocity of 17km/s which results in a very big Impactor.

Comment: @ErikHall, all those formulas would look much nicer when formatted with Mathjax, here i tutorial https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica , man i sit down, Crunch the Numbers, do some CG, use Company Textures and all i get is a "Could look nicer" D: But yeah, you are right that it looks pretty trash. Maybe if i find the Motivation...

Comment: You somehow got a KE value with the unit of Newtons, but it should be Joules. We can't say anything about the *force* required to change the moon's rotation, since we don't know the timeframe over which that force is applied - all we can say for sure is the total *energy* required to change the rotational period. If the value of 10^30J is correct, it's worth noting that's greater than the gravitational binding energy of the moon - the impactor is carrying enough energy to knock every bit of the moon into the farthest reaches of the universe! I'm surprised the moon survives the simulations.

Comment: But isnt the conversion 1 to 1 ? 1 Joule is 1 Nm ? Or did i miss something, I probably did some mistake D: 

Well my Simulations where small in scale so detail is lost. But i worked with the Calculated Mass and a Velocity of 17km/s. on Impact. As well as pretty small Angles. The Sim´s are Partical Based to so its all just an Estimation. But the Moon did fall apart once the Angles go to vertical @NuclearHoagie

Comment: @NuclearHoagie, what could be is that: I didnt use the Energy value, just Mass and Velocity. So if i did an Error, the Sim wouldnt care. So the Energy is probably way less but the Mass is still in the Margin

Comment: 1 J is indeed 1 Nm, but that implicitly assumes that the force is delivered over the space of exactly 1m. You could deliver a 2N force over 0.5m, or a 1N force over 1m and get the same change in energy. Not sure exactly where the misstep is, but any calculations involving forces/Newtons will have underlying assumptions about *how* the energy gets delivered (over what distance/time) - probably better to work only in Joules, as we only need to care about the beginning and final states.

Comment: I am pretty sure i just forgot at some point that i was dealing with Values in Nm. Ill go over it but also edit in a disclaimer that something is not right about the Energy. 

To be fair, the Sims are pretty violent and i was supprised that the Impactor is this big. I assume something about the sizes of Ceres before. But 8 times for massiv quiet a bit more. 

Thanks for pointing the error out !

Comment: Sorry, but this is fundamentally wrong. When an impactor impacts the Moon, it comes with a certain momentum and with a certain kinetic energy. You must account for *both* quantities; calculating only energy won't get you far, because energy is mutable -- most of it will become heat. Moreover, at the speeds at which celestial bodies move around, [Newton's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impact_depth) of impact depth holds, and thus you can estimate the deceleration of the impactor, and thus both the force it exerts upon the Moon and the time during which that force is exerted.

Comment: The goal was not to get an exact answer for the total Energy but more and approximation that could be used to estimate the sizes of the Impactor. 

As i said in the disclaimer, i know that it is not right. Yet the result i got still seems to be in the right Boundaris since the Sim didnt blow up the Moon. Sadly there is no good way for me to check the Resulting Rotation of the moon. Since the sim is partical based, you can only estimate it.

Comment: Another nitpick: The velocity of asteroids hitting earth is much higher than that of asteroids hitting the moon. As the asteroid falls from the level of the moon orbit to the earth, it picks up the majority of its speed. Asteroid impacts on the moon are in the single digit $\frac{km}{s}$ range.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica 100% true. I only gave the wiki a brief look and it makes sense that they list the Impact speed, which will be higher because the Asteroid falls.down.

To defend myself though, the Velocity has a x² term so it helps a lot in downsizing the Impactor.

But still, fair and true point !

Comment: Your impact velocity is too high.  For the slower-moving objects the impact velocity at Earth is mostly due to Earth's gravity--and the moon is far enough out that your impactor won't have picked up much from Earth yet.  17 km/sec at the moon is from the outer solar system.

Answer (score 0):

The moon is rather huge.

Let's see how much energy is in a moon, rotating at one rotation per 280 days.
(as change over its current rotation, which keeps it nicely tidally locked)
You need to impart an equatorial surface rotational speed of 0.451m/s to the whole moon.

Pretend the moon is a perfect sphere, and homogenous. It should give a close enough answer.

280 days = 24192000 seconds
Moon mass = 3.348e22 kg
Moon radius = 1737100 m
Rotational energy of anything: EKr = 0.5 * I * ω²
Moment of Inertia of a sphere:  I = ⅖ MR²
We need total energy change, so energy of final system - energy of starting system should be considered.
Current rotational rate = 1 rotation per 28 days. (this is an approximation, that greatly simplifies the visualization. We need to speed rotation by 1 percent. actual figure is something like 27.3 days)
New rotation rate = 1.01 rotation per 28 days.

So its rotational kinetic energy to be added is: 47602087335057431774500.90073402379 Joule
Koff koff..  call it 4.76e22 J

That is only the energy of 227532 Tsar Bomba nuclear explosions.

!!Note that this is the amount of energy that must be successfully coupled with the Moon, not expended on lightshows, hypervelocity ejecta, or material that fails to stick to the moon.

I hope your incoming asteroid is a very, very large one, and coming in at a very slow speed, so that it squishes rather than just chews a corner out of the Moon.

---

To answer the question: The moon as a whole will definitely survive the event. The energy imparted is *many* magnitudes below the gravitational binding energy of the moon(which is 1.2 x 10e29 joules). Even if the moon is pulverized (and it wont be), it will still occupy the same orbit +- less than 0.5m/s speed. It will still mass the same, +- negligible amount, unless the incoming meteor was actually a medium-large sized moon.

The main difficulty is imparting that much energy/momentum with a single hit, without seriously re-surfacing vast areas of the Moon. You do not want a small, fast impactor, that will just splash. You need a large, slow one.

Comment: @MikeScott I think you miread the question. The OP wants the moon to rotate a bit faster or slower, so that it appears to rotate once per 280 days as seen from Earth. So it needs to CHANGE its rotational speed by.... one revolution per 280 days. Only this *change* in rotation need be added.(total energy related to total rotational speed, of course)

Comment: I think it would be better to calculate the required impulse instead of energy. Then you can derive the required asteroids mass as a function of its impact speed, and from there you can calculate the excess energy that will be generated by the impact which will heat the moon and hurl huge amounts of material into earth orbit.

Comment: Shouldnt you also consider that the moon at this scale behaives more like a >Fluid. Giving any sort of Rotation to it would involve a metric fuckton of Mass. Like close to Earth and Theia back in the days.
Not an expert but i think your statment of "very large Asteriode" is a bit off. Better "fucking Ceres"

Comment: How large is a *"very large"* asteroid? How slow is a *"very slow"* speed? This answer begins by calculating something and then it lets itself vanish into fog and handwaving.

Comment: Nice answer, simple and substancial. This "New rotation rate = 1.1 rotation per 28 days." 1.1 instead 1.01. Not sure which number was used in actual calculation. Idk also maybe to mention that it is symmetrical task so both 0.9 and 1.1 possible. Maybe it could benefit from example asteroid, typical passby speed around 5-6 km/s which brings us in e16 kg territory with current number, in some cases, and it is 4 orders of magnitude below ceres mass, for an ideal case.  Hm, I guesse we have to account that while massdriver launching mined rocks from moon, which direction u would like it to spin?